# I'm unable to connect to (or ping) the localhost address, 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking

I started troubleshooting after booting up my PC. 
`ping 127.0.0.1` fails with

```
unable to contact IP driver. General failure
```

A `tracert` for `127.0.0.1` returns

```
unable to contact IP driver. Error code 1753
```

I can see the adapter in the Device Manager.

I've restarted my machine and modem/router, uninstalled and reinstalled drivers for NIC (integrated into MOBO), and reset the TCP/IP stack with the `netsh winsock reset` and `netsh int ip reset` commands.

When I try and use the `ipconfig/release` or `/renew` commands, I get the message

```
An error occured while releasing interface ethernet : The RPC server is unavailable
```

I've also tried using a USB to Ethernet adapter, and I'm still having the same issues.

Comment: Sounds like it’s time to reinstall Windows. Traffic to `localhost` isn’t going through any physical network interface.

Comment: Have you done anything to your hosts file? That is the first thing  I would check and possibly clean up.

Comment: What happened that caused you to decide to ping your localhost?

Comment: JakeGould I haven't done anything to my hosts file, i tried sfc /scannow as admin, but no fix. I pinged my localhost because I couldn't ping my router, so I checked the loopback